# Nginx does not serve css and js from upstream servers

Tags: nginx, jboss, nginx-reverse-proxy

i am trying to migrate from Apache with mod_jk for Jboss to Nginx[proxy_pass]

**what i am trying to achieve**:
i have an Nginx server that sends all requests to upstream jboss v5 servers. that includes static content. so there is no static content on Nginx.

**issue i face**:

issue 1:
when i open http://hostname i get jboss home page that is good.
when i open http://hostname/uri i get app page with partially loaded images. i can see in chrome developer tool that it is not loading few css/js and png images.

issue 2:
when i try to refresh http://hostname/uri couple of times [2 -3 times] i start getting 404 continuously and that to from Jboss.

below is my nginx conf:

```
http{
include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
sendfile on;

upstream jboss {
server <external ip>:8080 ;
server <another ip>:8080 ;
}

server {
listen 80;
root /opt/html;
server_name localhost;

location / {
proxy_pass http://jboss;
}
}#server
} # http
```

**what i tried**:
i tried to access the individual jboss url directly and it loads perfectly and all the css/js and png images are loaded perfectly.

i tried with normal error log and it wont write anything. when i tried with debug it wrote heavy logging that i did not understood.

the attached image shows developer tool:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWCCr.jpg)

attaching part of debug info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPnC5.jpg)

Comment: use `proxy_pass http://jboss/` test.

Comment: @Pandurang i tried it but still an issue. every thing works fine without upstream server. (proxy_pass http://server:port/uri)

Comment: share access and error log entry for review.Also try with`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`
         `proxy_pass http://jboss$request_uri;`

Comment: @Pandurang, no luck. still same issue

Comment: Did you find solution for this @Rajesh??